# C# image collision

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Hi guys basically this is a code for zombies walking now what I want to do is when I click the zombies they disappear, how can I do that? Or how can I do if the zombies walking when collided with another image they would disappear? Like when a bullet hits them.

```
public class Gaston {
        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }
        public Image Image { get; set; }
        public int Colspan { get; set; }
        public int Rowspan { get; set; }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
         DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;
         List<Gaston> Gastons;
         int timesTicked = 0;
         int timesToTick = 10;
         Image zombieImg;
         public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Gastons = new List<Gaston>();
                DispatcherTimerSetup();
                Zombie();

        }


        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void Zombie()
        {
            Gaston newGaston = new Gaston
            {
                Colspan = -10,
                Image = new Image(),
                Rowspan = -10,
                X = -10,
                Y = -10
            };
            BitmapImage bmp;
            bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri (this.BaseUri, "/Assets/zombie.png"));
            newGaston.Image.Source = bmp;
            Gastons.Add(newGaston);    

            Grid.Children.Add(newGaston.Image);

        }
        private void ZombieWalks()
        {
            foreach (Gaston me in Gastons)
            {
                me.Image.Margin = new Thickness(me.Image.Margin.Left - 10, me.Image.Margin.Bottom - 10, me.Image.Margin.Right + 10, me.Image.Margin.Top + 10);
           }

        }




        public void DispatcherTimerSetup()
        {
            dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            dispatcherTimer.Start();
        }

        void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {

            AddZombie();
            timesTicked++;
            ZombieWalks();
            if (timesTicked > timesToTick)
            {

            }

        }
        private void AddZombie()
        {
            if (timesTicked == 5)
            {
                    Zombie();
                DispatcherTimerSetup();
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that WPF or Silverlight?

Comment: No, it's windows store app.

Comment: What is the WIndows store app, why you just don't use XNA or something similar like that ?

Answer (score 1):

Hook the Tapped event on your image (and turn IsTapEnabled to true). Then, in that event, remove the zombie.

```
BitmapImage bmp;
bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri (this.BaseUri, "/Assets/zombie.png"));
newGaston.Image.Source = bmp;
newGaston.Image.Tapped += GastonTapped;

....
private void GastonTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
// remove the zombie.
}
```

Also - I highly suggest you use a Canvas to position your elements. Much much easier.